# What happens under the hood when calling an async function from a sync function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, async-await

A:

```
const fetchDataASync = async () => {}
```

B:

```
const fetchDataSync = () => { fetchDataAsync() }
```

I just started out learning useEffect in React, and I noticed that if you put A directly in its callback function, you'd get warning: "Effect callbacks are synchronous to prevent race conditions."

Yet if you put B there instead, it runs without any warning, which makes me wonder:

1. What is the difference between calling an async function directly and calling a sync function that calls that async function?
2. How come one can cause race condition and the other can't?

Comment: It's basically impossible to turn an async function into a sync function, so calling `const fetchDataSync = () => { fetchDataAsync() }`  "sync" is extremely misleading, to say the least, and reveals a probable knowledge gap in the author. Effect callbacks are supposed to be synchronous cleanup functions, although why React can't await the result is a good question to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the difference between calling an async function directly and calling a sync function that calls that async function?

The main difference (in the examples you've given) is that you're not *returning* the Promise that will complete once the asynchronous actions are done. Are more direct translation would be:

```
const fetchDataSync = () => { return fetchDataAsync() }
```

> How come one can cause race condition and the other can't?

You're misdiagnosing the symptoms. By changing the callback to not return a Promise, you've hidden the problem under a layer of indirection. You no longer get that particular warning, but the danger is still there.

The warning is issued because by returning a Promise (which all `async` functions do) you'd probably be assuming that `useEffect` would wait until your promise is resolved before moving on through React's rendering lifecycle. They're saving you the headache of trying to understand why Strange and Inexplicable Things keep happening, by telling you up front that asynchronous stuff doesn't belong in that callback.

> What happens under the hood when calling an async function from a sync function?

The high-level answer is that the asynchronous function will execute until it hits the first truly asynchronous operation (like I/O), and then it will return a Promise to the synchronous function. Anything that's supposed to happen after that Promise (things after an `await`, or in a `then()` callback) will be treated as a callback that would eventually get executed when/if the asynchronous operation completes.

In the code you've provided, the "async" function has no truly async operations, so it finishes and returns a completed Promise synchronously. But that Promise is ignored by the calling method, which also returns without doing anything meaningful.